# setImageResource Not working for some icons in android

Tags: android

I am trying to use setImageResource in one of my custom adapter.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    NavDrawerItem current = data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.getTitle() + current.getIcon());
    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.account_circle);
}
```

both account_circle and account_home icons are available in drawable folder.
Everything works fine with

```
holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.account_home);
```

But when i try to draw account_circle

```
holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.account_circle);
```

It does not show any icon for that?

What is wrong here? How to fix this?

Comment: what about `setImageDrawable`

Comment: I have resource ID in NavDrawerItem current. That i have to use. Resource ID is getting printed fine.

Comment: Did you ever try with `setImageDrawable` ?

Comment: `holder.imgIcon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.account_circle));` Let me inform please .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya  I tried this. It is also not working..

Comment: Please check the size of account_circle image it should be less than 1 mb like 200-500 kb

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal `account_circle` have huge size ? Is it `.PNG` ?

Comment: This is how I am creating account_circle `<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" android:pathData="M12,19.2C9.5,19.2 7.29,17.92 6,16C6.03,14 10,12.9 12,12.9C14,12.9 17.97,14 18,16C16.71,17.92 14.5,19.2 12,19.2M12,5A3,3 0 0,1 15,8A3,3 0 0,1 12,11A3,3 0 0,1 9,8A3,3 0 0,1 12,5M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12C22,6.47 17.5,2 12,2Z" />
</vector>`

Comment: what about `setImageBitmap` ?

Comment: Just now tried setImageBitmap  too. still not working.

Comment: got the point , You are using `Vector` . Use `Drawable drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(getResources(), R.drawable.account_c‌);` Then set `drawable` .Hope this helps .

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal solved ??

Answer (score -1):

You can try this as well `holder.imgIcon.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.account_circle));`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you post a link to the documentation where we can find `setImageResource` method of `ImageView` which takes `Drawable` as parameter? **This will not even compile as there is no such method**

Comment: Thats mistake. I should write `holder.imgIcon.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.account_circle));`